# iOS User Experience Guidelines - login/register dialogs

Tags: ios, user-experience

I thought the [Apple iOS User Experience Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1) would include recommendations around providing login / register dialogs (toggling between the two etc). I can't find any. Does anyone know if recommendations for this exist, and if so, can you provide a link to the recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find anything as specific as what you're looking for. If there were guidelines/restrictions on everything, every app would look identical.

There is a section in the documentation you mentioned that talks about [Alerts, Action Sheets and Modal Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW39). It has some good information more generally on these kinds of interface elements (which are the kind of thing you may use to create your required login and register dialogs).

If you're looking for some inspiration on more colourful login and register screens, take a look at some of [these](http://www.webdesignshock.com/login-design/) designs which are well suited to the iOS platform.

If that's not enough, take a look at some existing apps for inspiration.

The only advice I would give in terms of login and register dialogs (in general), would be to not ask the user for too much information. An email address and a password is sufficient. If you demanded any more information, I can guarantee the sign-up rate would be affected. This is even truer in the mobile context where people use their mobile device in short bursts. You can always collect more information (if you require it) after the person is registered.

**Source:** A background in human computer interaction & mobile interaction design.

Comment: The link is gone, probably replaced by https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html